# When does the Mishna use the word "Hem" and when does it use the word "Hen"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I always assumed that Hem and Hen are masculine and feminine, but I see that the Mishna uses them quite interchangeably:

"שלשה תריסין הם" - Masculine with Hem

"שלש עגלות הם" - Feminine with Hem

"שלש ערבות הן" - Feminine with Hen

(From Kelim chapter [24](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%92))

Comment: How does this relate directly with Judaism? You have asked a question regarding Mishnaic Hebrew. Questions about the Hebrew language, when not specifically relating to Judaism, are [off-topic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think this is on topic. Maybe because שלש ערבות are receptacles and which תריסין and עגלות are not and therefore assume the role of  הן,

Comment: Additionally I remember reading when Rebbi compiled the Mishna  he set it up in a manner which is primarily concerned more about effectively conveying the required information  than masculine/feminine forms. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @ezra, the Mishna is part of Judaism, and understanding it is an act of Judaism. This question is specifically about the Mishna, not generically about some dialect of Hebrew. It is therefore about Judaism and on-topic, IMO.